# Mongo shell : can't update log level (setLogLevel is not a function)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I am trying to increase my mongo log level without success:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
connecting to: test
> use TreeDB
switched to db TreeDB
> db.setLogLevel(5,"query")
2018-01-23T12:11:28.221+0100 TypeError: Property 'setLogLevel' of object TreeDB is not a function
```

How to correctly use this function?

```
> db.setLogLevel
TreeDB.setLogLevel
```

db.help() does not output this function.

docs.mongodb references it here since 3.0: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setLogLevel/

I am using ubuntu 16.04, mongoshell 2.6.10, mongo: 3.6.2 (via docker)

Comment: it will support only from version 3.0

Comment: mongoshell version 3 and above will support this, it will not work even if mongodb version is greater than 3.

Comment: mongoshell is following the same versionning as mongo : I must update. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comments, I have to install at least 3.0 version of mongoshell.

This should be done following https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/